# What causes this error with pygooglevoiceupdate?

Tags: python, google-voice

I'm trying to send text messages using google voice, and python. I am using something called pygooglevoice (The updated version) found here: https://code.google.com/r/kkleidal-pygooglevoiceupdate/

Sadly, when I tried to send a text message this error was returned:

raise ValidationError('There was a problem with GV: %s % response)
googlevoice.util.ValidationError: There was a problem with GV: {u'data': {u'code': 2046}, u'ok': False}

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already figured it out, the pygooglevoice project used Google client auth to authenticate with username and password. Google has had that method deprecated for quite a while and finally disabled it. Only OAuth2 is allowed and no one has updated the code to make use of oAuth.